# how to add a class to an element when i click a different element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `input` that is supposed to add a class of `clicked` to another element with an id of `#zip` when clicked. Here is the code:

```js
$('#billing_zip').click(function () {
    $('#zip').addClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
#zip {
    color: #444;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 35px
}
.clicked {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chkField">
        <label for="billing_zip">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);check_address('billing');" class="txtBoxStyle hasPlaceholder" tabindex="10" size="10" value="" id="billing_zip" maxlength="15" name="billing_zip">
        <!--START: req_billing_zip--> 
        <img width="12" height="12" alt="" src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif"> 
        <!--END: req_billing_zip-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="zip">zip</div>
      </div>
```

I don't know why the above jQuery is not working.

Comment: As far as I can see your code is working just fine. `clicked` class is getting applied. http://jsfiddle.net/8L5qdeu7/

Comment: don't forget to wrap your jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){//Your Jquery Code//});`

Comment: add id='billing_zip' in label. You declare billing_zip as custom attribute(for). But you select it as id.

Comment: i dont know why it is working now but it is sorry.

Comment: Its working Check Your files if jquery is loaded and its code placed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v5o0rL9/1/) here. Use document.ready if required. One important point i found out is that, if the placeholder text on input box is lengthy, then it covers up entire input box area and doesn't allow to trigger click event. refer the jsfiddle.

```
$('#billing_zip').click(function () { 
    $('#zip').addClass('clicked');
});

$('#zip').click(function () { 
    $('#zip').addClass('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to declare id for billing_zip.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#billing_zip').click(function () {
    alert('hi');
    $('#zip').addClass('clicked');
});
});
```

```css
#zip {
    color: #444;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 35px
}
.clicked {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chkField">
        <label id="billing_zip" for="billing_zip">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);check_address('billing');" class="txtBoxStyle hasPlaceholder" tabindex="10" size="10" value="" id="billing_zip" maxlength="15" name="billing_zip">
        <!--START: req_billing_zip--> 
        <img width="12" height="12" alt="" src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif"> 
        <!--END: req_billing_zip-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="zip">zip</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working OK

It could be 2 possible issues:

1. You are missing to add the **jQuery** reference:
2. You should wrap your code inside the `document.ready` event:

   $(function(){
     $('#billing_zip').click(function () {
       $('#zip').addClass('clicked'); 
     });
   });

Answer (score 0):

If this only what you want. Then you can do directly like:

```
$('#billing_zip').click(function () {
    $('#zip').css("display","none"); // or you can use hide or fadeout property.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I wrapped your jQuery code in a "$(document).ready" it worked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#billing_zip').click(function () {
   $('#zip').addClass('clicked');
 });
});
```